# How to print members of a class when one of the properties of the class is a list

Tags: c#

I have a class in which one of the properties is a list:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I want to print out, for each `Course ID` and Course `Name`, the list of students enrolled in the course.

I've got a way to print out the various `CourseIds` and `Course` `Name`, namely:

```
foreach (Course course in courses)
{
    resultLabel.Text += course.FormatDetailsForDisplay();
```

Where:

```
public string FormatDetailsForDisplay()
{
    return String.Format("Course ID: {0} - Name: {1} <br/>", this.CourseId, this.Name);
}
```

But I have no idea how to iterate through the students for each course and print their details.

Comment: You've got a `foreach` loop demonstrating how to iterate over your "courses" collection, now write a similar one to iterate over the "Students" for each "course" in your loop...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
foreach (Course course in courses) 
{
  resultLabel.Text += course.FormatDetailsForDisplay();
  foreach(var student in course.Students)
   resultLabel.Text += "student:" + student.Name;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but string concatenation is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ForEach`:

```
courses.ForEach(FormatDetailsForDisplay);

public void FormatDetailsForDisplay(Course course)
{
   string f = String.Format("Course ID: {0} - Course Name: {1} ", course.CourseId, course.Name);
   foreach (var item in course.Students)
   {
     f += "Student Name:" + item.Name;
   }
     resultLabel.Text += f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom method to get a string to display, I would use a similar approach for each part.

```
public string FormatDetailsForDisplay()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Course ID: ").Append(this.CourseId);
    sb.Append(" - Name: ").Append(this.Name).Append(" - Students: {");
    sb.Append(this.Students[0].FormatDetailsForDisplay());
    for (int i = 1; i < this.Students.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(", ").Append(this.Students[i].FormatDetailsForDisplay());
    }
    sb.Append("} <br/>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
// Update FormatDetailsForDisplay() for the Students class depending on how you built it
public class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public string FormatDetailsForDisplay()
    {
        return String.Format("Name: {0} - Age: {1}", this.Name, this.Age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I never thought to use the StringBuilder approach.

Answer (score 0):

To keep is short and sweet, add an `override ToString()` to your `Student` class that returns the `Student` information very similar to how the `FormatDetailsForDisplay()` method displays the information about the `Class`.  The `override ToString` would look like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // Add what ever properties you have
    // I just used ID and Name
    return String.Format("\tID: {0} - Name: {1}\r\n", ID, Name);
}
```

Now, in the `FormatDetailsForDisplay()` you can do something like:

```
public string FormatDetailsForDisplay()
{
    return String.Format("Course ID: {0} - Name: {1}\r\n{2}", 
                         this.CourseId, 
                         this.Name,
                         String.Join("", this.Students.Select(s => s)));
}
```

Put it all together and you have something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Course course = new Course {
            CourseId = 123456,
            Name = "Math",
            Students = new List<Student>()
        };

        course.Students.Add(new Student() {
            ID = 11111,
            Name = "John Doe"
        });
        course.Students.Add(new Student() {
            ID = 22222,
            Name = "Jane Doe"
        });

        Console.WriteLine(course.FormatDetailsForDisplay());
    }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public string FormatDetailsForDisplay()
    {
        return String.Format("Course ID: {0} - Name: {1}\r\n{2}", 
                             this.CourseId, 
                             this.Name,
                             String.Join("", this.Students.Select(s => s)));
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("\tID: {0} - Name: {1}\r\n", ID, Name);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Course ID: 123456 - Name: Math
    ID: 11111 - Name: John Doe
    ID: 22222 - Name: Jane Doe
```

See working example here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/arFF4t

Comment: Thank you!  I like this approach.

Comment: @DwightMendoza You're welcome... If this answer was helpful, kindly click the check mark please for your answer to be solved. If it was really helpful, consider giving it an upvote:-)